# "Unsupported version" error restoring a schema backed up with the same version it was dumped

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I am trying to backup and restore a schema from a remote server to a local system. Even though `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` report the same version, the later fails with the familiar "Unsupported version" error (log below). I have seen this error before, when `pg_restore` is an older version than `pg_dump`, but never when the versions match. What could be the cause?

```
$ psql -h server.somewhere -p 5432 -U user -d database
Password for user user:
psql (16.1 (Ubuntu 16.1-1.pgdg22.04+1), server 14.10)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

database=> SELECT version();
                                                 version
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 14.10 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-20), 64-bit
(1 row)

database=> \q

$ pg_dump --version
pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 14.10 (Ubuntu 14.10-1.pgdg22.04+1)

$ pg_restore --version
pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 14.10 (Ubuntu 14.10-1.pgdg22.04+1)

$ pg_dump -h server.somewhere -p 5432 -U user database -n schema_new -F t > ~/temp/schema_new_2024-01-29.backup

$ pg_restore -d wosis ~/temp/schema_new_2024-01-29.backup
pg_restore: error: unsupported version (1.15) in file header
```

Comment: The file you dump is different from the file you restore.

Comment: As Laurenz says, the file you created is not the one you used to restore with--their names are different. And the one you used to restore with was not created by v14, or you wouldn't get that error.  It had to have been v16 or v17.

Comment: @jjanes I run it again with the same results, the file name was some copy/paste. Both systems seem to have the same Postgres version, 14.10. The server runs on RedHat, the client Ubuntu.

Comment: Why are the `pg_dump` and the `psql` from your PATH different versions?  Maybe you have some kind of wrappers which are playing naughty games.  Find the absolute paths to the actual binaries, check the versions there, and use absolute paths to invoke the commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu allows multiple installed versions of the PostgreSQL client tools, and selects dynamically the version at run-time according to the 8-step rule
explained in [pg_wrapper manpage](https://manpages.org/pg_wrapper):

> It determines the configured cluster and database for the user and
> calls the appropriate version of the desired program to connect to
> that cluster and database, supplying any specified options to that
> command.

Presumably what happens here is that you have both version 14 and 16 of the client tools installed, and a local PostgreSQL server version 14.

So when you do "pg_dump --version" or "pg_restore" to a local server, it assumes you want version 14.

But when you do "pg_dump -h some-remote-server" it doesn't know which version is the destination server, so it uses the latest version, version 16. So you're dumping with version 16 and reloading with version 14, which is not supported.

To avoid that, there are multiple solutions by configuring or adding command-line options, but the simplest one is to invoke directly the version you want for instance with
`/usr/lib/postgresql/16/bin/pg_dump` instead of `pg_dump`.

You may also uninstall the versions you don't want, although you might be confronted with dependencies problems, and future updates might want to install them again. The packages are named `postgresql-client-NN`.